# Incorrect syntax near 'S' when passing string parameter

Tags: c#, syntax-error, sqlcmd

In c# I have the following lines of code:

```
 string mySqlStmt = "SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tlGenericName WHERE ( UPPER(ltrim(rtrim(genericName_str))) = '" + this.cmbGenericName.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "' ) ) > 0 THEN"
   + " ( SELECT top(1) isnull(genericNameCode_str, '') FROM tlGenericName "
       + " WHERE ( UPPER(ltrim(rtrim(genericName_str))) = '" + this.cmbGenericName.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "' )  ) ELSE '' END";
```

Then I use an SqlCommand (in c#) for executeScalar.
However, I get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'S'
```

I have noticed that this occurs for some records (a break in the parameter  value); for example:

> 'BANDAGE P.O.P.ROLL TYPE 1;200MMX2.7M 12's'

How can I safely pass the string parameter in Sql in the designer (c#) ?

Comment: Quotes within string literals must be doubled, IIRC.

Comment: You have to use SqlParameter in order to parametrize an query. Here is a simple [walkthrough](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `single quotes` something like below:

```
this.cmbGenericName.Text.Trim().ToUpper().Replace("'", "''")
```

Also as a suggestion as mentioned by Peter in the comment avoid using inline SQL statements to avoid the [`SQL injection attacks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15) by using the [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and its [`parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters)!

Comment: Thank you for the right answer: just what I needed when I didn't want to use SqlParameter in order to parametrize in a query. I have marked as answer.

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it using string interpolation :

```
var number = 2;
var exampleString = $"Number is : {number}";
```